# Infinite next/prev post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the code below, I'm trying to set an infinite next/prev post loop solely for pages (as opposed to posts). The last page I have, the previous button links to a page, but the next button links to the first post I have available. How can I change it to only target pages?

```
<div class="port-nav left">
        <?php 
            /**
             *  Infinite next and previous post looping in WordPress
             */
            if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
        ?>
                <p class="prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?></p>
        <?php
            } else { 
                $first = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">&larr; Previous Post</a>';
                wp_reset_query();
            };
        ?>
        <?php       
            if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
        ?>
                <p class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link'); ?>
        <?php
            } else { 
                $last = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); $last->the_post();
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Next Post &rarr;</a>';
                wp_reset_query();
            }; 
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shot in the dark, as I'm not able to test this at the moment:

```php
$last = new WP_Query('post_type=page&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC');
```

Comment: Hm, that seemed to have changed the target from pages to posts. Thank you. A follow up, how can I have this target only posts with the same category?

Comment: Any ideas? Can I have this code target only posts in the same category?